# JQL query to find epics that are not "child of" any initiative

Tags: jira, parent-child, jql

I'm looking for a way to search amongst the epics in my Jira project that do NOT have a "child of" relationship to any Initiative - i.e. there are no "is child of" under "Issue Links". I've searched like crazy but not found the right recipe. All help appreciated!
Regards
Chris